# Updating Application data in a Qlik Sense Application though Extension

Tags: qliksense

Is it possible to change the application data from  a extension?

I was creating a visual extension(table) in which if I change the value of a cell I should be able to change the value in the application level (not in database level),How can I achieve this?

Changing the value in `Qhypercube.[].qDataPages.qDataPages...` is only changing the value in Extension level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is data persistence, since Qlik Sense itself is not a data warehouse or a true "data store" in the traditional sense. When you load data from a database into an app and it goes through the app's load script, it's then cached to the underlying QVF file for the app. Updating the data would need to happen at either the source level (the database in this case), an intermediary store like a QVD, or "on the fly" via variables and chart scripting. Those first two options are persistent and that third one is not.

That's why if you look at other similar Qlik extensions that enable users to input data, they are "writeback" solutions, as they update the underlying database that the app is pulling from. You can find a few examples of those [here](https://developer.qlik.com/ted/5ec39450b55aa40017c3aa40), [here](https://developer.qlik.com/ted/5ec24d2f40a2f0001a2b078d), and [here](https://developer.qlik.com/ted/5eb177184514100012efccc9).

A few existing ones also take the approach of outputting to QVDs, which could be your best bet if you want to avoid updating a database. See [this one](https://developer.qlik.com/ted/5f106afaef2d88001a923c43) as an example, as well as their implementation docs [here](https://community.vizlib.com/support/solutions/articles/35000167801-vizlib-writeback-table-guides-vmc-setup-qvd-csv-txt).

You could probably achieve all of this with a combination of:

- Getting the hypercube of your (updated) table ([more info](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2022/Subsystems/EngineJSONAPI/Content/service-genericobject-gethypercubedata.htm))
- Create a session app ([more info](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2022/Subsystems/EngineJSONAPI/Content/service-global-createsessionapp.htm))
- Write to a new or existing QVD ([more info](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2022/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Sense_EngineAPI/CreatingAppLoadingData/EditDataLoadScript/get-content-file-and-create-QVD-file.htm))
- (Partial) reload the current app ([more info](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2022/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Sense_EngineAPI/CreatingAppLoadingData/LoadData/reload-app.htm))

This would all depend on the Update rights of the users of the app, though.